# Permutation cycles in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I.

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, permutations

Nathan Jacobson's Basic Algebra I Second Edition, Section 1.6 Cycle Decompositions of Permutations, page 51, exercise 4 says:

Show that if $\alpha$ is any permutation then

$$\alpha (i_1 i_2 \cdots i_r) \alpha^{-1} = (\alpha(i_1)\alpha(i_2) \cdots \alpha(i_r)).$$

This makes no sense.  Suppose $\alpha = (12)$ and $(i_1 i_2 \cdots i_r) = (12345)$.  Then

$$\alpha (i_1 i_2 \cdots i_r) \alpha^{-1} = (12)(12345)(12) = (31452)$$

but

$$(\alpha(i_1)\alpha(i_2) \cdots \alpha(i_r)) = (\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\cdots \alpha(5)) = (21345).$$

I really dislike this text, because it seems he's constantly abusing notation.  Can anyone see what he's trying to say?

Comment: I get $(12)(12345)(12)=(13452)$ and $(\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\alpha(3)\alpha(4)\alpha(5))=(21345)$.  Since $(13452)=(21345)$, this is consistent with what you say Jacobson wrote.

Comment: @MichaelHardy How do you get $(13452)$? Following the mapping from top to bottom: $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
3 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @TravisBemrose I can understand frustration with texts, but Jacobson really is not known for bad notation. What is unclear? Conjugation by a permutation is the same thing as applying the permutation to the elements of the cycle. Modulo the typo that Michael Hardy pointed out in your first cycle, that's what is going on.

Comment: @TravisBemrose The bottom row of this matrix is *not* the cycle produced by the composition. All of your columns top-to-bottom paths are correct, though. They say that $1$ winds up at $3$, $3$ goes to $4$, $4$ goes to $5$ , $5$ goes to $2$, and $2$ goes to $1$. That cycle is $(13452)$, not the last row of your matrix.

Comment: @rschwieb Ah.  I have to go $(1\to n_1, n_1 \to n_k, n_k \to \dots)$ not $(1\to n_1, 2 \to n_2, 3 \to n_3 \dots)$.  I find this text so unclear as to be almost unreadable.  I've been getting through this class by supplementing my reading with other texts.

Comment: @TravisBemrose OK, well good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You computed the product incorrectly. In general, note that $$\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(i_1))=i_1,\;\;(i_1\cdots i_r)i_1=i_2,\;\;\alpha(i_2)=\alpha(i_2)$$ Therefore the image of the element $\alpha(i_1)$ under the permutation $\alpha (i_1\cdots i_n)\alpha^{-1}$ is the element $\alpha(i_2)$. Similarly, we have $$\begin{align}\alpha(i_2)\mapsto &\alpha(i_3) \\ \alpha(i_3)\mapsto &\alpha(i_4) \\ \vdots \\ \alpha(i_r)\mapsto &\alpha(i_1)\end{align}$$ Therefore one of the cycles for the permutation is $$(\alpha(i_1)\alpha(i_2) \cdots \alpha(i_r))$$ Consider any element $x$ *not* in that cycle. Then $\alpha^{-1}(x)\ne i_j$ for any $j$, because that would contradict the fact that permutations are bijections and hence one-one. Thus the image of $x$ will be $$\alpha(\alpha^{-1}(x))=x$$ All other elements are therefore fixed, and the equality follows. Note that this is a conjugation.